# Different SHA1 Hash result between Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, hash, sha1

I've a big problem.
I using this C# function to encode my message:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file_or_text);
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
String hashText = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");
```

On java side, I use this snippet:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
sha1hash = md.digest();
```

My message is: Block|Notes|Text !£$%&/()=?^€><{}ç°§;:_-.,@#ùàòè+

I have this result:

```
(C#)   8EDC7F756BCECDB99B045FA3DEA2E36AA0BF0875
(Java) 2a566428826539365bb2fe2197da91395c2b1b72
```

Can you help me please??
Thanks...

Comment: Why are you using iso-8859-1 encoding in the Java snippet and not on the C# snippet?

Comment: What are the byte arrays before you calculate the hashes? They might not be the same (maybe because you use ASCII and ISO-8850-1 encoding)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819794/sha1-c-sharp-equivalent-of-this-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you seem to be comparing ASCII bytes to Latin1 bytes. Try switching

```
md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
```

to this

```
md.update(text.getBytes("ISO646-US"), 0, text.length());
```

That might solve your problem.

(Or switch C# to use Latin1)

What is happening in your program your `GetBytes` method is returning different values for the same characters depending on encoding, so our nifty SHA1 hash algorithm is getting passed different parameters resulting in different return values.

Comment: Can I change code on C# side?
On java side is more difficult for me... (I can't touch Java side)

Comment: Jon Skeet explains it on his post.

Answer (score 4):

The change to use ISO-8859-1 on the C# side is easy:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(file_or_text);
```

However, both this and ASCII will lose data if your text contains Unicode characters above U+00FF.

Ideally if your source data is genuinely text, you should use an encoding which will cope with anything (e.g. UTF-8) and if your source data is actually binary, you shouldn't be going through text encoding at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public static string Sha1encode(string toEncrypt) {
    // Produce an array of bytes which is the SHA1 hash
    byte[] sha1Signature = new byte[40];

    byte[] sha = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
    SHA1 sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();
    sha1Signature = sha1.ComputeHash(sha);

    // The BASE64 encoding standard's 6-bit alphabet, from RFC 1521,
    // plus the padding character at the end.

    char[] Base64Chars = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
            't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
            '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/', '=' };
    // Algorithm to encode the SHA1 hash using Base64
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int len = sha1Signature.Length;
    int i = 0;
    int ival;
    while (len >= 3) {
        ival = ((int) sha1Signature[i++] + 256) & 0xff;
        ival <<= 8;
        ival += ((int) sha1Signature[i++] + 256) & 0xff;
        ival <<= 8;
        ival += ((int) sha1Signature[i++] + 256) & 0xff;
        len -= 3;
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 18) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 12) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 6) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[ival & 63]);
    }
    switch (len) {
    case 0: // No pads needed.
        break;
    case 1: // Two more output bytes and two pads.
        ival = ((int) sha1Signature[i++] + 256) & 0xff;
        ival <<= 16;
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 18) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 12) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[64]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[64]);
        break;
    case 2: // Three more output bytes and one pad.
        ival = ((int) sha1Signature[i++] + 256) & 0xff;
        ival <<= 8;
        ival += ((int) sha1Signature[i] + 256) & 0xff;
        ival <<= 8;
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 18) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 12) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[(ival >> 6) & 63]);
        sb.Append(Base64Chars[64]);
        break;
    }

    string base64Sha1Signature = sb.ToString();
    return base64Sha1Signature;
}
```

Comment: Can you say what he was doing to cause the difference?