# SHA1 C# equivalent of this Java

Tags: c#, java, sha1

Looking for the same equivalent to this method in C#

```
try {
          MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
          md.update(password.getBytes());
          BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
          hashword = hash.toString(16);
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
          }
}
return hashword;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super easy in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CSharpSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string HashPassword(string input)
        {
            var sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] outputBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            return BitConverter.ToString(outputBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string output = HashPassword("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sha1CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx). It provides a good amount of flexibility. Like most of the algorithms in [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx), it provides methods for handling byte arrays and streams.