# Hashing with SHA1 Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, hash, byte, sha1, hashcode

I want to hash given `byte[]` array with using `SHA1` Algorithm with the use of `SHA1Managed`.
The `byte[]` hash will come from unit test. 
Expected hash is `0d71ee4472658cd5874c5578410a9d8611fc9aef` (case sensitive).

How can I achieve this?

```
public string Hash(byte [] temp)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your excpected hash is a hexadecimal value, so it doesnt matter if it's case sensitive e.g. `hex(e) == hex(E)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819794/sha1-c-sharp-equivalent-of-this-java

Answer (score 218):

For those who want a "standard" text formatting of the hash, you can use something like the following for .NET 5 and newer:

```
static string Hash(string input)
    => Convert.ToHexString(SHA1.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
```

This will produce a hash like `0C2E99D0949684278C30B9369B82638E1CEAD415`.

If you are stuck on pre-.NET 5 where `Convert.ToHexString` is not available, you can do:

```
static string Hash(string input)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in hash)
        {
            // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
            sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or for a code golfed .Net Framework version:

```
static string Hash(string input)
{
    var hash = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    return string.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

Comment: It bugs me that this solution doesn't dispose the SHA1Managed object, because it is marked as Disposable.  This post could be handy when optimizing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/991863

Comment: @sky-dev, I usually agree with `IDisposable`, but a quick trip to [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha1managed.cs,5d9dbfaea57ea7b8) shows that nothing interesting happens in `.Dispose()`

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the Dispose implementation as well.  It would just speed GarbageCollection a tad.  It probably isn't a big deal in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Mitch If it implements the IDisposable interface then what happens in the reference source shouldn't matter. Should they ever change it for any reason such that the .Dispose() call becomes important, your previously working code is now causing a problem. Relying on looking into the bowels of a framework to determine what you can get away with is a path to a maintenance nightmare. I highly suggest following the documentation and correctly handling disposable objects, it'll save you pain in the long term.

Comment: @unenthusiastic use, Haha, thanks.  I wasn't sure what the purpose of documentation was...  (The code in my production applications is the one from the top, but the circumstances of the second make me comfortable enough that it would be equally supportable in all but the tightest loops.  `IDisposable` is semi-optional when dealing with non-side-effecting classes.)

Comment: just because something is IDisposable doesn't mean you should call Dispose() on it.  source: I've done server-side SharePoint development.

Comment: For the second version, you can also replace the select + concat logic with aggregate: `new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)).Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, y) => x + y.ToString("x2"))`

Comment: What is the "X2" for?

Comment: @ijt, X2 tells it to use two hexadecimal digits per byte.  `x2` means lowercase, `X2` is uppercase

Comment: If you need to support machines set to FIPS 140-2 compliance, replace `SHA1Managed` with `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` instead (but keep the rest the same).  But to future-proof your code, use a stronger hashing algorithm.  Even if your use case is not security-sensitive, these methods can be disabled through system policy.

Comment: @JoeyAdams, sure.  That is only needed for .Net 2 through .Net 4.7.2, though.  .Net 4.8 make the change automatically for you ([Managed cryptography classes do not throw a CryptographyException in FIPS mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7.2-4.8#managed-cryptography-classes-do-not-throw-a-cryptographyexception-in-fips-mode))

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks for the refinement.  Though this only applies if the application *targets* .NET 4.8, or if the app config uses `UseLegacyFipsThrow=false` as described in your link.

Answer (score 41):

```
public string Hash(byte [] temp)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(temp);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You could also specify the encoding when converting the byte array to string as follows:

```
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash);
```

or

```
return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hash);
```

Comment: If they want a hex string then Base64 is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: @Joey: Against the answer given by GrantThomas, the member indicated that they need to return a string

Comment: @MerveKaya: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "it didnt work". What does the incoming byte array represent? How did you determine "SHA1Managed"-hashing the incoming byte array should give you `0d71ee4472658cd5874c5578410a9d8611fc9aef` as the output?

Comment: Byte[] hash comes from unit test. In the question they wrote that expected hash is 0d71ee4472658cd5874c5578410a9d8611fc9aef. It comes from unit test

Comment: @MerveKaya: See my update on how to use `Encoding` when converting the hash to a string

Comment: No, unfortunately it failed again

Answer (score 19):

This is what I went with.  For those of you who want to optimize, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/991863.

```
    public static string Hash(string stringToHash)
    {
        using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToHash)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to use BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(bytes)).Replace("-", "") since I didn't want the dashes introduced by BitConverter. After that it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can "compute the value for the specified byte array" using [`ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx):

```
var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(temp);
```

If you want to analyse the result in string representation, then you will need to format the bytes using the `{0:X2}` format specifier.

Answer (score 9):

Fastest way is this :

```
    public static string GetHash(string input)
    {
        return string.Join("", (new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
    }
```

For Small character output use `x2` in replace of of `X2`

Comment: SHA1Managed implements IDisposable, so you would probably want to dispose it when done with it to free up resources.

Comment: It's not the fastest way, it's merely packed into a single line.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl well, yeah :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw my hat in here:

(as part of a static class, as this snippet is two extensions)

```
//hex encoding of the hash, in uppercase.
public static string Sha1Hash (this string str)
{
    byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (str);
    data = data.Sha1Hash ();
    return BitConverter.ToString (data).Replace ("-", "");
}
// Do the actual hashing
public static byte[] Sha1Hash (this byte[] data)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed ()) {
    return sha1.ComputeHash (data);
}
```