# Java equivalent for creating hash

Tags: c#, java, hash, sha

I have a piece of C# code, and I'm trying to rewrite it in java.

But I'm not getting the expected result in my Java code.
What am I doing wrong?

C# code:

```
string response = pwd + challenge;
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = 
   new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
SHA1.Initialize();
byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(response));
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
foreach (byte b in hash)
    builder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
```

Java code:

```
MessageDigest messageDigest  = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest((PASSWORD + challenge).getBytes());

    String result = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
```

Comment: SHA1 is not suitable for passwords.  Use PBKDFv2.

Comment: I would recommend you to check if you're really getting the same bytes on both c# and Java

Comment: I love the way you use the full type name instead of `usings` and place several sentences in the same line separated by `;`

Comment: @HighCore: with your rep, wouldn't an edit be better than such a comment?

Comment: @wvp: Try to keep your code examples free of scrollbars by keeping line-lengths short. It's much easier to read.

Comment: Double-check that you're using the same "system default encoding" on each side, or better yet, don't use a "system default," use a constant encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: Could you also post some desired output for the Java code ? I'd gladly help, but I don't have Windows. Also, you could have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205066/different-sha1-hash-result-between-java-and-c-sharp?rq=1